# ASP.NET forms authentication randomly redirects to login page

Tags: asp.net, forms, redirect, authentication

This reporting system application works well for all clients except 2. 
They log in without issues, but when trying to click on a link after they login it redirects them back to the login page.Then after we login again we click on that same link, it goes through but if we click on another link after, it redirects back to login page. Sometimes it works well for some time, then randomly when we click on a link it redirects back to login page.

[image]